# LWJGL 3 failing to render textures properly with slick-util compatible version with LWJGL 3

Tags: java, opengl, render, game-engine, lwjgl

I have recently started rewriting my game in LWJGL 3, and it is so different.
I tried looking for tutorials, and this person used this slick-util compatible with LWJGL version 3.
I followed the tutorial and watched the 30 minute tutorial almost three times and couldn't figure out what was wrong, I checked it's github repository and still couldn't figure out why I couldn't get my texture loading properly.

Here is how my texture looks rendered with my code [image]

Here is his github repository for the tutorial 
[enter link description here](http://github.com/CodingAP/lwjgl3-tutorial/tree/a42df2319bf456322cdf105fa988c431da0fe5ee/tutorial8)

Here is the tutorial video 
[enter link description here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shLtzHF34Gk)

Skip to timestamp: 32:02

I really need help I tried all day I can't get this working!
Let me know if sharing code is necessary, because maybe one of you might have had this bug already and already know the solution.
Thank you

Comment: I'd like to also mention i copied his texture coordinates so they are exactly the same as in his Github!

Answer (score 1):

The vertex specification does not match the the attribute indices of the shader program:

> ```java
> pbo = storeData(positionBuffer, 0, 3);
> // [...]
> cbo = storeData(colorBuffer, 1, 3);
> // [...]
> tbo = storeData(textureBuffer, 2, 2);
> ```

Your vertex shader:

> ```c
> #version 460 core
>
> in vec3 position;
> in vec3 color;
> in vec2 textureCoord;
>
> out vec3 passColor;
> out vec2 passTextureCoord;
>
> void main() {
>   gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
>   passColor = color;
>   passTextureCoord = textureCoord;
> }
> ```

Your fragment shader

> ```c
> #version 330 core
>
> in vec3 passColor;
> in vec2 passTextureCoord;
>
> out vec4 outColor;
>
> uniform sampler2D tex;
>
> void main() {
>   outColor = texture(tex, passTextureCoord);
> }
> ```

The attribute indices are not automatically enumerated (0, 1, 2, ...). The  attribute `color` doesn't even get an attribute index, because it is not an active program resource. `color` is set to the interface variable `passColor`, but that variable is not *used* in the fragment shader. Hence this shader program has only 2 active attributes and the attribute indices of this attributes are not specified. Possibly the indices are 0 for `position` and 1 for `textureCoord` (that is what most hardware drivers will do), but you cannot be sure about that.

Use [Layout Qualifier (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)) for the [Vertex shader attribute indeices](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Vertex_shader_attribute_index):

```c
#version 460 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 textureCoord;

// [...]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I will test it tomorrow Thanks so much for helping, I was gonna be worried no one would help, but just had to wait a few hous.

Comment: @purplex It is very difficult to help if the code is not posted in the answer. It is not intended to provide the source code in an offsite resource. Note, this question will stay here, but will the github repository still be there in the future? You have to add the relevant code to the question if you'll get help. Other users may downvote and vote to close your question. You were lucky that I spent the time.